# how to get value of checked boxes in li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below piece of html. it has UI with LI's each having a check box in it. Now i want to know values of all thoses li's which have been checked. but i am not able to think how to do it. is there any function or method to do this.

HTML :

```
<ui>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="left select-all"><h3>Select all</h3><div class="clear"></div>
</li><li class="sub_checkbox_list_box">
<input type="checkbox" class="left selector" value=8>
<h3>ruleSetproductSelectionFilterTrial1</h3>
<input type="hidden" value=2013-12-25>
<div class="clear"></div>
</li>

<li class="sub_checkbox_list_box">
<input type="checkbox" class="left selector" value=12>
<h3>ruleSetSudhanshuSelectAllBugTrial2</h3>
<input type="hidden" value=2013-12-27>
<div class="clear"></div>
</li>

<li class="sub_checkbox_list_box">
<input type="checkbox" class="left selector" value=13>
<h3>ruleSetSelectAllBugTrial3Sudh</h3>
<input type="hidden" value=2013-12-27>
<div class="clear"></div>
</li>
</ui>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: Lets give you a hint `$.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function(){ //do somethig});`

Comment: actually i am tried this way $('#leftSection li:gt(i) .selector').val(); but soon realised that this was absolutely rubbish. Nothing is changing when we select. how to get hold of it.

Comment: @Satpal - perhaps you mean `$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){ //do something });`...

Comment: @Satpal thanks. just let me try...

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple method,

```
var checkedValues = $("li input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function () {
  return $(this).val();
});
console.log(checkedValues.get());
```